# Virtualbox static IP addressing with external router

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a TP-link router and I would like to create a LAN network with static     IP addressing. My host is an Ubuntu 14.04 and I have 2 another Linux guest OS. I set up all of them and the router can ping the host machine and the 2 guest each other, but the real machines can not ping the guests and inversely. They are in bridged network settings. IP addresses:

```
Network :192.168.0.0
GW: 192.168.0.1
PCs:192.168.0.5 .. 0.6 .. 0.7 
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
```

How can guest OS reach the external (real) network? Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that all your VMs use a Bridged network (in the vbox settings under Network), instead of NAT (the default option). When you use NAT, its like your VMs are on their own network, with their own filrewalling router, so pings can't reach the guests (but guests can ping outbound). By using a bridged network the VM will appear on your physical network, and you can configure the VM's OS to use a static IP address within your physical networks IP space. That way everyone can talk both ways with everyone else.

Comment: I am using bridged network option. Actually everything was working fine when I used DHCP. After that, The real layer can't establish connection with the virtual layer. :(  I had to restart the host and it works. :|